# How to connect Mindstorms EV3 to AppInventor?

Tags: app-inventor, lego-mindstorms

AI2 apps can connect to NXT brick over bluetooth using the NXT* blocks but the same do not work with EV3. Does anyone know how to connect EV3 to AI2?

Comment: Why the down-vote? Is the question unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an app in the App Inventor Gallery that uses the BluetoothClient component to control an EV3.
http://gallery.appinventor.mit.edu/#page%3DApp%26uid%3D27866001%26label%3DEV3

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create your own program to exchange data by Bluetooth using the EV3 mailbox. Once you are able to send and receive text messages between ai2 and ev3 it's easy to program the ev3 to perform actions according to the received text.